# Different file system JVM working in a same server

Tags: java

In our 64bit server need to run 2 JVM, that is 32bit JVM and 64bit JVM parallel. We need to call on application from 64bit JVM and run in 32bit JVM.
So I need to know that there is any problem happen if run like this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple JVMs I suggest you install both and specify which JVM you want to use explicitly, i.e. don't use the default path to find `java` even if it happens to be the right one at the moment.

Comment: 64bit jvm using for JBoss 32bit JVM using for other java application. That means both are running at same time

Comment: You can run any number of versions at the same time. All you need is a supported 64-bit OS.